# Bubble Sort for Dual Linked Lists in Java

Tags: java, linked-list, bubble-sort

I'm attempting to implement bubble sort for dual linked lists, but I get a `NullPointerException`.

Here is the code:

```
public void bubbleSort()
{           
    DLLNode<E> tmp = this.first; // (1)
    DLLNode<E> tmp2 = null; // (1)
    boolean flag = true;
    while(flag)
    {
        // (2)
        flag = false;
        while(tmp.succ!=null)
        {

            if(tmp.element2.compareTo(tmp.succ.element2)<0)
            {
                tmp2.element2 = tmp.element2;
                tmp.element2 = tmp.succ.element2;
                tmp.succ.element2 = tmp2.element2;
                tmp2.element1 = tmp.element1;
                tmp.element1 = tmp.succ.element1;
                tmp.succ.element1 = tmp2.element1;
                flag = true;
            }
            tmp = tmp.succ;
        }
    }
}
```

Another thing: this method that I used I think will iterate the list only once, and won't turn back at the beginning. I thought moving `tmp` and `tmp2` from `(1)` to `(2)` would solve the problem. But I still receive a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: can you provide a complete runnable code?

Comment: This seems to be the problem: `DLLNode<E> tmp2 = null; // (1)` (you create a null pointer). Later on, you `tmp2.element2 = tmp.element2;`. You can't access `.element2` on `null`. Produce a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to receive a working answer.

Comment: `tmp2` virtually does not exists, since you set it to null.

Comment: @ggorlen it works my friend. Thank you for the answer and for the edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line seems to be the problem:

```
DLLNode<E> tmp2 = null; // (1)
```

Here, you've created a null pointer. A few lines later, without any further assignments to `tmp2`, you attempt to access `tmp2.element2` using this null pointer, which crashes the program:

```
tmp2.element2 = tmp.element2;
```

Re-evaluate your design and ensure all of your objects have been initialized before trying to access their properties or methods.